# Wordpress site extremly slow in IE

Tags: wordpress, performance, internet-explorer, debugging

This problem has been discussed before, but it seems the solution is never the same.

[My website](http://www.clickology.nl) is quick to load in FF and Chrome, but extremely slow in IE-8 and -9.

I've tried disabling all plugins. I'm running W3TC with minify on. IE is not reporting any js errors.

Can't switch themes because the site is live and I'm scared to lose custom stuff I did.

I know some PHP and JS, but please be gentle as I'm still a Newb.

**Update 1:**
Just adding my Header.php. If anyone sees anything strange, please tell me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="<?php bloginfo('language'); ?>">

<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-39366119-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />

<title><?php wp_title(' '); ?> <?php if(wp_title(' ', false)) { echo ' : '; } ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>

<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="http://www.clickology.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/favicon.ico" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style-font.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<?php if ( get_option('solostream_responsive_off') != 'Yes'  ) { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style-responsive.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<?php } ?>

<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />

<?php wp_head(); ?>

<?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div id="outer-wrap">

    <div id="wrap">

        <div id="header">
<div style="float:right; vertical-align:top" id="header-widgets" class="clearfix">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar('header-widgets'); ?>
</div>
            <div id="head-content" class="clearfix">
                <?php if ( get_option('solostream_site_title_option') == 'Image/Logo-Type Title' && get_option('solostream_site_logo_url') ) { ?>
                    <div id="logo">
                        <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_option('solostream_site_logo_url'); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" /></a>
<div class="description"><p style="font-family:arial;color:#594c46;font-size:13px;"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></p></div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <div id="sitetitle">
                        <div class="title"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></div>
                        <div class="description"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'banner468head' ); ?>
            </div>

            <?php if ( get_option('solostream_header_contact_on') == 'Yes' ) { ?>
            <div class="header-contact-info">
                <?php if ( get_option('solostream_header_contact_email') ) { ?>
                    <span class="head-email">
                        <strong><?php echo get_option('solostream_header_contact_intro'); ?></strong> <a href="mailto:<?php echo antispambot(get_option('solostream_header_contact_email')); ?>"><?php echo antispambot(get_option('solostream_header_contact_email')); ?></a>
                    </span>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ( get_option('solostream_header_contact_phone') ) { ?>
                    <span class="head-phone<?php if ( get_option('solostream_header_contact_email') ) { ?> sep<?php } ?>">
                        <?php echo get_option('solostream_header_contact_phone'); ?>
                    </span>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>

        <?php if ( get_option('solostream_show_topnav') != 'no' ) { ?>
        <div id="topnav">
            <?php if (has_nav_menu('topnav')) { ?>
                <ul class="nav clearfix">
                    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('container'=>false,'theme_location'=>'topnav','fallback_cb'=>'nav_fallback','items_wrap'=>'%3$s')); ?>
                </ul>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <ul class="nav clearfix">
                    <li id="home"<?php if (is_front_page()) { echo " class=\"current_page_item\""; } ?>><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><?php _e("Home", "solostream"); ?></a></li>
                    <?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>
                </ul>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>


        <?php if ( get_option('solostream_show_catnav') == 'yes' ) { ?>
        <div id="catnav">
            <?php if (has_nav_menu('catnav')) { ?>
                <ul class="catnav clearfix">
                    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('container'=>false,'theme_location'=>'catnav','fallback_cb'=>'catnav_fallback','items_wrap'=>'%3$s')); ?>
                </ul>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <ul class="catnav clearfix">
                    <?php wp_list_categories('title_li='); ?>
                </ul>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'banner728' ); ?>
```

Comment: FWIW, switching themes should not make you lose stuff. If you are still afraid, you can download the theme directory then upload it if something changes.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, the theme is the problem. Also, I didn't lose anything (heart still pounding). What should I do next?

Comment: Open the IE developer tools (F12), go to the network tab and load your site. This should tell you what components take the longest time to load.

Comment: No Network Tab in IE8, however Fiddler shows AJAX (contact form 7) and admin-ajax take the longest.

Answer (score 0):

I see you load a few scripts in the header, try relocate stuff in footer.php. Only load necessary stuff in the header. Could help.

And test without...

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

the to rule out, due it targets the browser where you encounter problems

Overall good practice to handpick stuff, disable and check.

Comment: Scripts are put in the header by the Plugins used. I think I moved some of them using minify, but I don't really know the difference between necessary and unnecessasary scripts. Tested without [if lt IE 9] as suggested, but it makes no difference.

Comment: hmmm... it must be either a plugin or the fact that minified stuff, might be that something went wrong there. Caching maybe? Did see a very long load time on some contactform 7  images.

Comment: did a google on CF7 and there is some stuff documented on it due it apparently is know for slowing down stuff. Though you mentioned that you tried to kill all plugins... anyway an [article](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-wordpress-plugins-affect-your-sites-load-time/) on the matter by wpbeginner.

Comment: Disabled CF7, disabled caching still slow in IE.

Comment: IE is not our friend is it... =) I checked the demo site [wp_radiance](http://wp-radiance.solostreamsites.com) on IE and there it seems ok. So if it ain't the plugins and it ain't the theme it must be modifications. You could make a header-temp.php and rename <?php get_header():?> to <?php get_header('temp');?> and start stripping stuff to see if the problem originates here. Can do the same with the footer.php. Also backup functions.php and strip stuff to do the same check. Careful with the last suggestion.

Comment: Really? No other way. I mean you're probably right. But the only things I did was, create a widget area in the header and add some Google Analytics code there.

Comment: Hmmm, than I'm out of ideas other than suggested. Doesn't take a whole lot of time though. I'm out of time here, hope you fix it. Let me know... I wonder what the issue is.

Comment: did the check on header, footer and functions. No succes.

Comment: What did the theme develop people say? Do they have a forum? I know that TinyMCE can slow stuff down when extra stuff is being loaded in there. Have had the experience myself with a theme called TryMee. Thye populated the editor with all kind of shortcode buttons. A way tot test this is to disable the visual editor via functions.php.

Comment: Basically they're not going to help because I altered the theme. I don't think TinyMCE is in there.

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of simple things you can do to improve the performance of your site. I've gotten a handful of WordPress sites to load in 1.5 seconds or less on cheap, shared hosting doing a few basic things:

1. Concatenate. Combining like files together.
2. Minify. Removing the spacing, line breaks and comments from files.
3. Smush. Removing unneeded data from image files.
4. Icon Fonts. Icon fonts are a lighter, faster alternative to image-based icons.
5. Compress. Reduce file size by up to 70 percent.
6. Cache. Telling browsers to keep static assets stored locally so that they doesn’t have to be re-downloaded every time they visit your site.
7. Page Structure. Adjusting the location of CSS and JavaScript files for faster rendering.

The whole process takes under an hour, but if it's your first time doing some of these things, may take a little bit longer as you're learning how it all works.

Here's a step-by-step tutorial I wrote: http://gomakethings.com/high-performance-websites/

Comment: Another awesome tool for WordPress is the [Plugin Performance Profiler](http://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/). It will tell you how long every running plugin takes when the page is produced.

Comment: Chris, thanks for the tips, but I really think I should find the bug first. Gerald, I know this plugin. It didn't show any problems with my plugins. The problem really seems to be the theme.

Comment: I have a hunch it's not a bug so much as a cross-browser quirk. Good luck!

Comment: By the way, running your site through YSlow, it gets a C. You really should try some of the performance optimization tips outlined in my article. Modern browsers are far better at selling out performance than older IE browsers are.

Answer (score 0):

There are some WordPress plugins that can make your website load faster. WordPress is the best CMS based platform for blog and websites but if you are having lots of content and images on website, it can take long time for loading and you are losing your visitors.

Check you Page Load time using Page load check!

W3 Total Cache basically compress CSS and JavaScripts in memory.

Check more plugins http://bit.ly/1fAYKv1